# Woocommerce single product page oversized on mobile

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On my website. I open my all page on mobile looking good. But on any single product page such as http://www.ilmthai.com/product/to001/ it have space on the right side.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXe2i.png)

It should not be dragged to the right.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in the head section of your header.php:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
```

And this in your stylesheet:

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```